# Use String outside thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I've been trying to fix this problem almost all day (or it feels like that), and I really can't do it myself. So I hope you can help.

First of all, I have a button that is clicked - when that happens, a txt file from the internet is read and saved in a String. While this is going on, a ProcessDialog appears to show that the file is retrieved.

In the code below you'll see a TextView called tv2, it is purely implemented for testing purposes.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.music);

    final TextView tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Button btnMusicAll = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnMusicAll);
    btnMusicAll.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            String wait = getString(R.string.pleaseWait);
            String retrievingInfo = getString(R.string.retrievingInfo);                             

            getReleaseInfoProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Music.this, wait, retrievingInfo, true);

            new Thread()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        headers = getStringFromUrl(getString(R.string.rlsHeaderURL));
                        setHeaders(headers,tv2);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        String error = getString(R.string.error0x01);
                        MessageShort(error);
                    }

                    // Remove progress dialog
                    getReleaseInfoProgressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }.start();              
        }
    });
}
```

And the method setHeaders:

```
public void setHeaders(final String hdr, final TextView tv)
{       
    try
    {
        runOnUiThread(
                new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {                           
                            tv.setText(hdr);
                    }
                });
    }           
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now, I want to be able to use the String 'headers'. Because I want to split it up and use it afterwards.
For example, I have been trying to expand the public void run() method above to the following:

```
public void run()
{                           
    tv.setText(hdr);
    hej = hdr.split("\n");
    MessageShort(hej[1]);
}
```

MessageShort is simply a Toast method that takes a String as parameter.
'hej' is declared as:

```
public String[] hej = {};
```

If 'hdr' ('headers') is "text01\ntext02\ntext03", 'hej' would be hej[0]=text01, hej[1]=text02, etc.

This also works ok, a Toast message appears stating "text02" for hej[1].

The real problem here is the fact that I can **not** use 'hej' or 'headers' outside these running threads. For example, if I - after the method btnMusicAll.setOnClickListener - write the same MessageShort statement (MessageShort(hej[1]);) - the application crashes! It also crashes if I try to use 'headers' somehow.

Please help.

Comment: Why do people always say "the application crashes", there are millions of ways an application can crash, could you be more specific?

Comment: Are you sure that you are accessing the 'hej' array after `onClick` action has been performed and the running thread has finished its execution?

Comment: better to create a small runnable program to reproduce this, so that it can separate other possible problem (the problem may not in hte above code, but in other code in your application) and others can help you easier.

Comment: @Nicklas A. I mean the program stops and the well-known popup box emerges saying "Force Close" (or what it says in English).

Comment: @eightx2 Yes, but that always comes with stack trace in the logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing.

I managed to make it work, but not sure if it's the best way to do it.

I use AsyncTask, and after I've dismissed the ProgressDialog in the onPostExecute method, I use the putExtra method for the Intent in which I need the String (that was retrieved from the internet). I'm sure this would work too in my old code above (without the use of AsyncTask).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me that an [Async Task](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) is exactly what you need. 
Create a class deriving from AsyncTask. override the doInBackground to download your Text and pass it. While doing you can send progress Messages. If you are ready override at least onPostExecute to define what should happen (In your case show your Toast)

Comment: Thanks @Rafael T for the suggestion. I've tried to implement it, but it's actually not solving my problem. Granted, this AsyncTask is easier than the way I did it originally. Check my code for the AsyncTask here: http://pastebin.com/mEYA8HbF, and now my onCreate method looks like this: http://pastebin.com/4N9pSJbY. Note my comment: the program crashes (force close) when I use `testStringArray` outside the AsyncTask thread. (`testStringArray` is declared like this above the onCreate method: `String[] testStringArray;`).

Comment: @eightx2 Ahh I got it! so actually only doInBackground has its own Thread and computes everything ASYCNHRON! onPostExecute is handled in the Thread which started execute. So AsycTask is NOT ready yet to get the String in your onCreate ;) ASYNC is a KEYword ;) for this you are provided with the callback onPostExcute! So do, whatever you want to do or to start there.  
If you wanna proccess it sycron I see no reason to do it in a differnet Thread or runnable

Answer (score 0):

since the program your show can not run, try to use and check the result.Not sure whether it works

```
public void run()
{                           
tv.setText(hdr);
String tmpStr=new String(hdr);
hej = tmpStr.split("\n");
MessageShort(hej[1]);
}
```